# Resolve compilation error “CS8601 Possible null reference assignment”

Tags: c#, parameters, compiler-errors, default, nullable

Since C# 8.0, the standard is non nullable variable by default. [Ref1](https://endjin.com/blog/2020/04/dotnet-csharp-8-nullable-references-non-nullable-is-the-new-default)

But in case of generics like this one:

```
    public static T PerfomIO<T>(Func<T> function, T defaultValue = default)
    {
        try
        {
            return function();
        }
        catch (IOException)
        {
        }

        return defaultValue;
    }
```

How to get rid of the compilation error "CS8601 Possible null reference assignement" that occur when I try to pass "default" ?

I want to support null value here. I do not want to disable the error message. I want to program it the way it should be.

I try to add Nullable in many ways without success.
I try [AllowNull] without success

[image]

Comment: You may look at [nullable analysis attributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/attributes/nullable-analysis)

Comment: That's not an error, is it (definietly not an exception)? Should only be a warning.

Comment: Have you tried removing the assignment and creating an overload with a single argument that calls this method with the default for the type? Not sure if that would help or not (but it should since the assignment is removed), and the functionality would be the same. i.e. `public static T MyFunc<T>(Func<T> function) { return MyFunc(function, default); }`

Comment: This question is being discussed on Meta: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/406609

Answer (score 18):

I found a few tricks although I had no idea why the project was forced to "nullable check" (found and details below). I look in the .csproj, .sln and elsewhere and didn't find any parameter that could force the null check.

I found 2 ways to workaround the problem I had:

- Solution 1: You can add the next line at the start of your .cs file:

  #nullable disable
- Solution 2: Change the parameter from `default` to `default!` where the `!` tells the compiler not to consider the nullable check.

I currently use `default!`.

Also just as reference, if your project forces null check but you can't find the option in your project or in your solution, then look for this article: [Customize your build](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/customize-your-build?view=vs-2019), perhaps you will find why the null check is forced. (All new since 2019).

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio 2022 you can add `.editorconfig` file to suppress those annoying messages (I sure hope you know what you are doing)

In the `.sln` file:

```
Project("{2150E333-8FDC-42A3-9474-1A3956D46DE8}") = "Solution Items", "Solution Items", "{32FE27E8-3094-4A72-8200-3A2639355EF0}"
        ProjectSection(SolutionItems) = preProject
            .editorconfig = .editorconfig
        EndProjectSection
    EndProject
```

and `.editorconfig` file content is:

```
[*.cs]

# CS8600: Converting null literal or possible null value to non-nullable type.
dotnet_diagnostic.CS8600.severity = none
```

There is a way to create this file and hook it up suing VS2022 by hovering over the issue:

[image: suppress CS8600]

I hope it will help someone